# How to use iTunes file import/export function with phonegap build

Tags: ios, html, cordova, phonegap-build, fileapi

I'm building a small app using apache cordova and adobe phonegap build.

I've added the filer.js wrapper for the html5 file api filesystem and it works like a charm.
I can write, list and open my files from within the app.

What i need to do is to retrieve files using iTunes and a dock cable (no wifi or internet available).

I tried lots of configs but can't get to a point where my app appears in the lists of app from which i can grab files.

So far my config.xml configuration for files is :

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<preference name="UIFileSharingEnabled" value="true" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />


<key>Plugins</key>
    <dict>
        <key>File</key>
        <string>CDVFile</string>
    </dict>

    <key>Plugins</key>
    <dict>
        <key>FileTransfer</key>
        <string>CDVFileTransfer</string>
    </dict>
```

This app will only be used with ios on iPad.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I believe this can only be done via a cordova plugin since only plugins can modify plist files. Here are the steps I took using cordova 4.3.0:

1. Create your plugin directory somewhere, outside your cordova project, let's say in /home/user/. The plugin consists of just one file and the directory structure looks like this:

   ```
   /home/user/com.mycompany.cordova.itunesfilesharing/
   /home/user/com.mycompany.cordova.itunesfilesharing/plugin.xml
   ```
2. In the plugin directory you need the plugin.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        id="com.mycompany.cordova.itunesfilesharing"
        version="1.0.0">

    <name>Enable iOS iTunes file sharing in Plist file</name>
    <description>iOS plugin for a custom Plist addition</description>
    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="UIFileSharingEnabled">
            <true/>
        </config-file>
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

3. Then you need to add this plugin to your cordova project:

   ```
   cordova plugin add /home/user/com.mycompany.cordova.itunesfilesharing
   ```

This will copy the plugin into your cordova project. Once added, you will see these added to your plist file:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

That's all I had to do, no config.xml changes needed. Just add the custom plugin. Then such an app will allow to access its Documents directory in iTunes.